# Send data from first angular 6 app to second angular 6 app using socket.io

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io

is there a chance to send e.g this data
`[{value1: 1, value2: 2}, {value3: 3, value4: 4}, {value5: 5, value6: 6}]`
from first angular 6 app to second app using socket.io and node.js server?

I've already tried send data between Angular 6 apps but second Angular 6 doesn't receive data

Comment: Did you try something? Can you show us your attempt, maybe some code to show your workflow?

Comment: of course it's possible. what does your architecture look like?

Comment: My architecture is two separate application, run on different port from localhost using node server js. Its working when i have open two apps at the same time only. I need click button on first app then open second app in the same window

Comment: Anyone know how to deal with it?